# Referencing a View in another XML file

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I have a ListView in a file called a.xml.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_above="XYZ"
        />
```

In a.xml, I also include another file called b.xml.

```
<include android:id="@+id/bottombar" layout="@layout/b" />
```

For one of the settings of the ListView, I want to reference an id (XYZ) that exists in b.xml.

Is there a way I can do this?

I've tried the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/bottombar" layout="@layout/b" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottombar_background"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where @id/bottombar_background exists in @layout/b, but Eclipse throws "no resource" errors at me.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? The proper syntax varies based on usage.

Answer (score 1):

After you have used `setContentView(R.layout.a)` you should be able to use `findViewById(R.id.my_id_in_b)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the XML?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use something like `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/my_id_from_b"` in your a.xml. Very important: it works only _after_ your include tag, not before (because at the moment it is parsed, the parser needs to know the id already)

Comment: I've tried this, but Eclipse throws errors at me, even after referencing the @id after the include tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax: android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_id_from_b". It prevents any reference issues.

The plus in this instance tells the compiler to do a second pass on the layout, looking for that id on the second time through. Try it out - I know it works, as I use this syntax all the time.

Comment: Won't this create a new instance of a View of the same name?  I *want* to reference the @id in @layout/b

Comment: I've revised my answer to illustrate the concept - I'm sorry, I used an incorrect example the first time.

Comment: Well, it compiles now, but I do not see @+id/my_id_from_b on the screen

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting that too - let me build up a test proj and see if I can get it working.